# How do I get the Facebook comment count for a URL in PHP in 2021?

Tags: php, json, facebook

I'm using the Facebook Comments plugin (from FB, not a WP Plugin) on my WP site.

I want to get the number of comments for a specific URL, so I can set it up to say "start the conversation" or "join the conversation"

I've done my research and found several variations on the code below posted as recently as April of this year:

```
$rest_url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json&method=links.getStats&urls=https://my.com/".$my_slug;
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($rest_url), true);
//  echo "Facebook Shares = " . @$json[0]['share_count'];
//  echo "Facebook Likes = " . @$json[0]['like_count'];
  echo "Facebook Comments = " . @$json[0]['comment_count'];
```

However, after some frustration, I realized I needed to dump $json and see what's in there:

`var_dump($json);`

and to just parse out the important part, there was a message inside:

`"REST API is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher (12)"`

There's a lot I don't understand about APIs and Facebook's system.

But... can you tell me what the current way of getting the comment count is now? I just need it in a variable and I can go from there.

Thanks for any help!

Chris

Comment: Facebook API documentation you can find at https;//developers.facebook.com/docs . The REST API you trying to use was deprecated in 2011.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/url, field `engagement`. You will need an access token for those requests though. (App token might probably do, but you'll need to be careful with request limits.)